# I have a plain text chat log for a twitch vod, is it possible to convert this file to json format?

Tags: json, twitch

So I found an archive from some old deleted twitch vods, and t[he chat logs from the same vod on an archive website](https://logs.ivr.fi/channel/forsen/2018/12/23). There's many tools on github to render the chat using the json file, but the logs I have are in plain text format. I can't find any way to do it with just the text format. Does anyone know if it would be be possible to somehow convert the plain text into json so the chat can be rendered? Thank you, I would be so appreciative if some smart person could figure this out.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
[2018-12-23 00:02:26] #forsen snusbot: Get a free channel subscription token & in-game loot every month with Twitch Prime forsenPrime : https://twitch.amazon.com/prime
[2018-12-23 00:03:56] #forsen blowmymnd: $rl blowmymnd
[2018-12-23 00:03:58] #forsen xzaniity: TriHard
[2018-12-23 00:03:59] #forsen supibot: blowmymnd, (1d, 6h ago) <blowmymnd>: NaM CO BANDAI ⁭
[2018-12-23 00:04:05] #forsen blowmymnd: NaM
[2018-12-23 00:04:58] #forsen matisaurusrex2003chile: hey bajs you know about the animal jam raid forsenScoots
[2018-12-23 00:05:05] #forsen snusbot: Fricolor got gifted a resub by DoggWon, that's 2 months in a row PogChamp
[2018-12-23 00:05:24] #forsen xzaniity: TriHard
[2018-12-23 00:05:28] #forsen blowmymnd: $rl blowmymnd
[2018-12-23 00:05:31] #forsen supibot: blowmymnd, (76d, 2h ago) <blowmymnd>: ppHop
[2018-12-23 00:05:37] #forsen blowmymnd: !rq
[2018-12-23 00:05:38] #forsen sosil_: blowmymnd: KKool Clap
[2018-12-23 00:05:46] #forsen snusbot: xZaniity, thank you so much for your 12 months of unbroken support to the Snus Brotherhood! forsenDDK forsenWhip
[2018-12-23 00:05:57] #forsen xzaniity: Pepega
[2018-12-23 00:06:06] #forsen surfaa: forsenFeels
[2018-12-23 00:06:21] #forsen xzaniity: Why even resub when he is oflnie PepeHands
[2018-12-23 00:06:32] #forsen xzaniity: He cant even pronounce my name forsenKek
[2018-12-23 00:06:57] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:00] #forsen akarres: 1 MIL BOYS
[2018-12-23 00:07:03] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:07] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:08] #forsen xzaniity: One mil PagChomp
[2018-12-23 00:07:09] #forsen akarres: PogChamp
[2018-12-23 00:07:14] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:18] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:21] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:23] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:24] #forsen digitalfruitcakes: !roulette all
[2018-12-23 00:07:24] #forsen snusbot: digitalfruitcakes won 390 points in roulette and now has 780 points! forsenPls
[2018-12-23 00:07:36] #forsen xzaniity: !roulette 1
[2018-12-23 00:07:36] #forsen snusbot: xZaniity won 1 points in roulette and now has 16127 points! forsenPls
[2018-12-23 00:07:39] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:42] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:45] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:46] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:47] #forsen xzaniity: 16k after 12 months monkaOMEGA
[2018-12-23 00:07:49] #forsen lemonlime187: PedoBear Clap ANY PEDOS IN THE CHAT?
[2018-12-23 00:07:54] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:56] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:07:56] #forsen xzaniity: thats it forsenK
[2018-12-23 00:07:57] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:10] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:12] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:14] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:17] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:18] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:19] #forsen lemonlime187: forsenFeels
[2018-12-23 00:08:20] #forsen cenrus has been timed out for 600 seconds
[2018-12-23 00:08:20] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:35] #forsen cenrus: AYAYA
[2018-12-23 00:08:36] #forsen blowmymnd: $rl blowmymnd
[2018-12-23 00:08:36] #forsen lemonlime187: forsenWeird
[2018-12-23 00:08:39] #forsen supibot: blowmymnd, (103d, 0h ago) <blowmymnd>: we won ZULUL ⁭
[2018-12-23 00:08:47] #forsen blowmymnd: ZULUL
[2018-12-23 00:09:50] #forsen haywoodjabroni: forsenE
[2018-12-23 00:11:01] #forsen tuntematon: !rq
[2018-12-23 00:11:01] #forsen sosil_: tuntematon: abom1 IceCold abom3 IceCold abom4 IceCold abom2 IceCold
```

Comment: Anything is possible if you write some code for it, and have a clear idea of the exact format you are aiming for. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: I was mainly looking for a way to convert the text into a json format so it would be readable for the program on github but I cant find anyway to do this from my research.

Comment: Why? Which part of the process are you stuck with? have you worked out what individual steps you might need to do in order to make such a conversion, and then tried to work out how each step might be achieved? The smaller the task, the easier it will be to research. And until you specify the JSON format you want, it's hard for anyone else to give specific suggestions. And since you haven't specified a programming language or tool, it's even harder to give specific samples etc. Please clarify all those things, then you have much more chance of getting a useful response.

Comment: P.S. As a general point, since you're new to the site (welcome!) I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer.Thanks.

Comment: P.P.S. What is "the program on github" exactly? There many, many programs on github - it's a giant code repository after all. What specifically are you referring to?

Comment: This one specifically: https://github.com/lay295/TwitchDownloader. I think it uses python which is a language I'm a bit unfamiliar with. I've done some research on converting plain text to json but can't find anything that would work for this program specifically. It looks like it needs specific data from the json and will break if you feed it anything else.

Comment: Ok. so, once more...what is the JSON format that is required, please? Don't make people go off and read random code to work it out.  Just tell us exactly what you need. Edit your question to include it. and you also still haven't explained exactly where you're stuck in terms of achieving it. Please review all my comments again, not just the last one.